# Converting SOAP Object into an EF Table for Database Insertion

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, soap, entity-framework-4

I have an array of custom objects being returned from a web service.
The objects are modeled in the database and I have created the edmx file with the model.

Is there a generic way to put these objects into their respective EF container?

There are about 50 different types of objects (with 20-30 members each) returned from I'd rather not create a class to convert each one.  I've tried several different flavors of converting but since the AddObject doesn't take an array I am stumped.

```
private MyEntities dbContext;
ResponseObject[] TheResponses;
using (MyWebService wsInstance = new MyWebService())
{
    TheResponses = wsInstance.DoStuff();
    dbContext = new MyEntities();

    dbContext.Table1of50.AddObject(<whatgoeshere>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic way is using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) but even this solution will have some limitations depending on difference between returned and persisted object. Manual solution is adapter pattern - perhaps this solution can be also done automatically by writing custom T4 template but again it depends on difference between returned and persisted object. Another possibility is overriding deserialization so that your instances of your classes are created instead of autogenerated classes (this mostly means create custom proxy).

So there are ways to do that but they are strictly dependent on difference between returned and persisted objects and on pattern. If the differences doesn't have the same symptoms among all related pairs of classes you can hardly do any automation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to adapt the webservice so he creates already your EF Objects which you can add directly to your entity context (with attach). But this means that your webservice has to know your EF types.

If this is not applicable you will have to create your objects...

Comment: The web service is maintained by another company, so changing the service is not an option.